# HttpClient login via Rest-API GET and subsequent POST

Tags: c#, rest, dotnet-httpclient

I'm trying to make a call to rest-api client to import a csv file.

To do so, usually you should login through the website and then click on the import button.
Both this actions are "doable" with an API request:

- Login:
  `/api/v1/get/auth/login/username/password/0`
- Import:
  `/api/v1/set/csv/import`

The `HttpResponseMessage` I get from the login is this one:

```json
{
   "date":"29/03/2023 17:49:01",
   "level":"4",
   "slevel":"INFO",
   "code":"0",
   "flags":"0",
   "ctx":"",
   "title":"MainController.authorizeUser",
   "msg":"200 - OK",
   "msgex":"User authorized",
   "idobj":"0",
   "ev_uid":"0",
   "idfireobj":"0",
   "objstate":"",
   "eventid":"",
   "payload":{
      "data":[
         {
            "parameter_name":"user_token",
            "parameter_value":"A8BDB5E9"
         },
         {
            "parameter_name":"cache_culture",
            "parameter_value":"it-IT"
         },
         {
            "parameter_name":"role",
            "parameter_value":"0"
         },
         {
            "parameter_name":"cache_theme",
            "parameter_value":"Default"
         },
         {
            "parameter_name":"maintenance_enabled",
            "parameter_value":"0"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

but, I don't know how to retain this login session, or how to set the `client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization` using this dataset.
Thus when I call the import api i get an Unauthorized 401 error.

I've searched all over the web, and tried setting the cookies (That i get from the login response) but with no positive feedback.

my code as I've left it after my last attempts:

```
var cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler() { CookieContainer = cookieContainer, UseCookies = true })
using (var client = new HttpClient(handler) { BaseAddress = new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:8086") })
{
    var homePageResult = client.GetAsync("/api/v1/get/auth/login/user/pwd/0").Result;
    var cookie = homePageResult.Headers.GetValues("Set-Cookie").SingleOrDefault();
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cookie))
    {
        //cookieContainer.Add(client.BaseAddress, new Cookie("X-Cookie", cookie));
        var split = cookie.Split("=")[1].Split(";")[0];
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("X-Cookie", split);
    }

    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    var response = client.PostAsync("/api/v1/set/csv/import", payload).Result;
    var result = response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    return result.IsSuccessStatusCode;
}
```

So, I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: Difficult to say without knowing the API details, but most likely, if it respects some standard practice, you need to add the "user_token" provided by the response as a header in any following request. You usually set this token as part of the "Authorization" http header. According to your code, it seems though the authentication is cookie based. Do you have more info?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have any more infos.
What I don't get it how do I use the informations obtained from the login api call to then call the import api and not get the unauthorized access error
I'm new to this kind of interactions using HTTPClient thus I may be doing things wrong.

The service that exposes this API is accessible from a webpage, written using Angular.
I don't know if this info is of any help actually

Comment: Side note please prefer `await` over `.Result`. (Or if you can't use `await` then prefer `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()`)